# Trigger on Single Field

Tags: apex, trigger, sobject

I was playing around with `Apex Triggers` and was wondering, suppose I had an object (for example `Account`), which contains a sub-object (such as the string `BillingAddress`).

Can I set a trigger on `Object.subObject`?

So Instead of creating a trigger on `Account` I want a trigger that fires off only when `Account.BillingAddress` is updated for example.

My idea is to just type in:

```
trigger TriggerName on Account.ShippingCountry (before insert) {

}
```

But this fails to compile. How should I accomplish this objective?

Answer (score 6):

You will create the trigger on the account and use the billingAddress as the criteria.

For Example

```
trigger example on Account(before update){

    for(Account a : trigger.new){
        if(a.BillingAddress != trigger.oldMap.get(a.id).billingAddress){
             //do something
        }
    }

}
```